# PyQt5 on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pyqt5, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to install PyQt5 on my Raspberry Pi 4. I work in a virtual env with Python 3.7 installed using `source env/bin/activate`
I've updated my pip version to 20.2.4.
If I use the command:`pip install pyqt5`, the installation takes too long, it continues displaying for hours:

*collecting pyqt5
Using cached PyQt5-5.15.1.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing wheel metadata .../*

I've tried to write `sudo apt-get install pyqt5` but I found out that the package is installed for Python 2.7 version which was installed as default version on my Raspberry.

How can I install PyQt5 correctly? I want to use it in Python3.7.
I previosly installed pyqtgraph with the command `pip` and I did not get errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`. There is only one question that the pyqt5 by that command doesn't work in the venv of PyCharm.

Fine I found that if the selected python interpreter is system interpreter, it also worked in PyCharm.